# Easy way to call a function on the main thread in Qt (PySide2)

Tags: python-3.x, qt, qt5, pyside2, pyside6

Is there any easy way to call a function or method in the main thread from any other thread or QThread?

I heard that `Slot`s and `Signal`s can be used as a proxy between a thread and the main thread but it feels like too much work to create such a proxy for every single time I want to transfer data to my main thread.

*(My answer describes a very universal way to acclompish this so I won't be providing a "minimal" example here, you can look at the answer.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt has a function called `invokeMethod` (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) that can be used to invoke a method on the main thread by using the `Qt.QueuedConnection` connection type.

In PySide however **this won't work if you want to call a function with arguments**!

**Solution:**

So to allow a similar and even easier functionality with PySide, I have written this class which can be used every time you want to run a function or method on the main thread:

```
from typing import Callable

from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Signal, Slot
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication


class InvokeMethod(QObject):
    def __init__(self, method: Callable):
        """
        Invokes a method on the main thread. Taking care of garbage collection "bugs".
        """
        super().__init__()

        main_thread = QGuiApplication.instance().thread()
        self.moveToThread(main_thread)
        self.setParent(QGuiApplication.instance())
        self.method = method
        self.called.connect(self.execute)
        self.called.emit()

    called = Signal()

    @Slot()
    def execute(self):
        self.method()
        # trigger garbage collector
        self.setParent(None)
```

This will internally create a `Signal` and a `Slot` without any parameters. The `Slot` however will be called on the main thread as it has been connected using `Qt.AutoConnection` (the default) and moved to the main thread with `moveToThread(...)`.
To make sure no function arguments get lost due to the garbage collector, the parent of the class is temporarily set to the `QGuiApplication` instance (you might need to change this if you don't rely on the `QGuiApplication`. Any `QObject` will be fine as the parent).

Here is an example on how to use this class:

```
InvokeMethod(lambda: print("hello"))
```

Comment: That seems an interesting usage. But I don't see an *actual* benefit on using it against a standard implementation of a QThread with custom signals. And I really mean that *I don't see it*, not that there's any: I just can't think of a situation for which this could be better than the alternative :-) Can you provide a practical case for which this could be *actually* useful, also considering code readability/maintanance aspects and performance issues?

Comment: @musicamante I am using an external library with a class I'm subclassing in my own project. In that class there is a method I am overwriting which is called by a new thread (not QThread). I can't inherit my class from QObject (to use Signals) because that class already has a different metaclass.
So in the end I'd always need to write a separate class just to proxy some function calls to the main thread. The solution here however allows me to solve this problem with a single line using the InvokeMethod class.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use a simple QObject "proxy" for the class? It would avoid the continuous instantiation for the invoke method. Also, consider that it's possible to mix QObject and other meta classes; it's not always easy (especially if you're not used to deal with mc), but it's generally doable.